# SQL one-to-one relationship

Tags: database-design

The relationship that I want to define is that

For every row in TABLE_A must map to every row in TABLE_B table.
However every row in TABLE_B must not necessarily be in TABLE_A.

I am trying to come up with a model and I am wondering if I can come-up with a relationship given the above rule

My initial thought was one-to-one but when I say Table A one-to-one Table B, I am assuming the vice versa is true too. I am pretty novice in database stuff, please correct me if I am wrong.

My end goal is to have this implemented in hibernate.

Comment: This is called one-to-one, true. To be exact, it's a `0:1`-to-`1`. You need a Foreign Key from TableA's primary key, referencing TableB(Primary key). No idea if Hibernate deals easy with such relationships.

Comment: This is One To Zero-or-One relationship

Comment: @ypercube so I can say that Table A (0:1 - to - 1) to Table B. Thank you